# Error When getting List from a class

Tags: android

I have a problem that, I have a serializable class which sets and gets multiple lists. I added a list into that but when I want to get that list from getter method it returns NullPointerException. That's why I mentioned here Error and Setter and Getter Methods for explaining the problem and How I retrive it.I don't know why and don't know how it will be removed? Can any one help me about this problem?

**Error Stack:**

```
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.equinix.android.common/com.equinix.android.showmyorders.ShowMyOrders}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at com.equinix.android.showmyorders.ShowMyOrders.onCreate(ShowMyOrders.java:87)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-24 13:04:18.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(529):     ... 11 more
```

**Class for Setting and Getting List:**

```
package com.equinix.android.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class BaseIBXValues implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
    private List<String> IBXId;
    private List<String> IBXName;
    private List<String> IBXNaturalKey;

    public List<String> getIBXId()
    {
        return IBXId;
    }
    public void setIBXId(List<String> IBXId)
    {
        this.IBXId = IBXId;
    }

    public List<String> getIBXName()
    {
        return IBXName;
    }
    public void setIBXName(List<String> IBXName)
    {
        this.IBXName = IBXName;
    }

    public List<String> getIBXNaturalKey()
    {
        return IBXNaturalKey;
    }
    public void setIBXNaturalKey(List<String> IBXNaturalKey)
    {
        this.IBXNaturalKey = IBXNaturalKey;
    }
}


**Code for Setting the value of arraylist:**
public class Parse_Json {

    String json_String;
    List<String> IBXId;
    BaseIBXValues ibx;------> It is the class where setter and getter mentioned

    public Parse_Json(String json_String)
    {
        this.json_String = json_String;
    }

    public void parse()
    {
        ibx = new BaseIBXValues();
        try{
        JSONObject ja = new JSONObject(json_String); 

        JSONArray  jo = ja.getJSONArray("ibx");
        for(int i=0;i<jo.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject j_data = jo.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("The id is:"+j_data.getString("id"));
            IBXId.add(j_data.getString("id"));
            LoginScreen.id.add(j_data.getString("id"));
            System.out.println("The Name is:"+j_data.getString("name"));
            LoginScreen.name.add(j_data.getString("name"));
            System.out.println("The naturalKey is:"+j_data.getString("naturalKey"));
            LoginScreen.naturalKey.add(j_data.getString("naturalKey"));

        }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ibx.setIBXId(IBXId);------------> set the list
    }
```

**Get the List from Getter:**

```
ibx = new BaseIBXValues();
        ibId = ibx.getIBXId();

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("The IBX ID:"+ibId.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: Whats line 87 in ShowMyOrders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to note:

In the `Parse_Json` class:

```
List<String> IBXId;
```

`IBXID` is never intiallized so it is `null`.

So later when it tries to add values to `IBXId`:

```
IBXId.add(j_data.getString("id"));
```

This will throw a NullPointerException.

But if your `JSONArray  jo = ja.getJSONArray("ibx");` returns a `jo` of size `0`, the line

```
ibx.setIBXId(IBXId);
```

will set `IBXId` to null

In the following code:

```
    ibId = ibx.getIBXId();    

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("The IBX ID:"+ibId.get(i));
    }
```

`ibId` is `null` because in the `BaseIBXValues` class, the line

```
 private List<String> IBXId;
```

doesnt initialize `IBXId`, so it s value is `null` so calling `ibId.get(i)` to it will result in a NullPointerException

**EDIT**

See your code modified here:

```
public class Parse_Json {

    String json_String;
    List<String> IBXId = new ArrayList<String>();
    BaseIBXValues ibx;------> It is the class where setter and getter mentioned
```

But when you call the getter

```
 ibId = ibx.getIBXId();    

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("The IBX ID:"+ibId.get(i));
    }
```

, you can make sure that you have a non-null value

```
ibId = ibx.getIBXId();
If(ibId != null) { 
    for(String index : ibId)
    {
        System.out.println("The IBX ID:"+index);
    }
}
```

**Edited**

```
List<String> ibId=Collections.emptyList();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showmyorders);
        ibx = new BaseIBXValues();
        ibId = ibx.getIBXId();
        if(ibId != null) { 
            for(String index : ibId)
            {
                System.out.println("The IBX ID:"+index);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**
This should be:

```
public class BaseIBXValues implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
    private List<String> IBXId = new ArrayList<String>(); // initialize to empty array of string
    private List<String> IBXName;
```

When creating the new `BaseIBXValues` object,

```
ibx = new BaseIBXValues();
ibId = ibx.getIBXId();
```

`ibId` should be an empty array of string

Comment: Problem remains same after assigning the Null values in List Variables.

Comment: Calling a method to a object set to `null` will result to a NullPointerException. You have to initialize to new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: You have to initialize `private List<String> IBXId = new ArrayList<String>();` in `BaseIBXValues` class. But be aware that if you use `setIBXId(null)`, the getter `getIBXId()` will return null; So you should probably check some null value before looping through `ibId`

Comment: Ya ccheneson, I already added your code but the problem remains same.

Comment: I would suggest then to use the debugger and go step by step and check for the value of the object you pass to `setIBXId`. And as David Olsson said, give the line where the exception happened (before you have made the modifications above)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3744/discussion-between-sanat-pandey-and-ccheneson)